# How to merge different models in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have the following initial situation:
My application processes data stored in the django db and some external data accessible through an REST API.

What would be the best "django style" approach to

1. Query data from db
2. Retrieve data from api
3. Merge data to a "proxy" model
4. return that proxy model to a view

Same for create, update, delete.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a proxy model, write a custom manager for the model which would do all the 1-4 steps. This will allow you to use other inbuilt features of Django like class-based views out-of-box.

See, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers

Comment: Where in the manager class should I implement the logic? If I modify instances in get_queryset it requires evaluating the queryset, right? If I want to get a single db entry it will call get_queryset and try to filter the results causing a large overhead.

Comment: The DB calls in Django are lazy calls. So overriding the `get_queryset` to add an extra filter will not result in a query to DB at that time. Instead, all the chain of filters in the hierarchy will be collected and queried only when a piece of code tries to access the data. So unless you do not access the data in get_queryset, it will not cause overhead.